# Has /etc/hostconfig actually gone away?

Tags: macos

I'm annoyed by the mere existence of the /etc/hostconfig file on my Mac. Every time I try to tab-complete in the shell to get to my /etc/hosts file, it stops short at "/etc/host" because of this name-competitor.

Examining the file contents:

```
# This file is going away

AFPSERVER=-NO-
AUTHSERVER=-NO-
TIMESYNC=-NO-
QTSSERVER=-NO-
MYSQLCOM=-NO-
```

...and looking through previous questions, it seems to me that it's possibly a useless vestige from an older version of OS X. So, given that I'm running Yosemite 10.10.something, is it safe to just delete the thing?

If nobody knows, I'm just going to try moving it sideways, but I figured it would be sensible to ask first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file does nos exists in my Yosemite install.

However, I have and older iMac on 10.7.5 that keep this file.

Consider backuping it up it and testing to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks; if it's not in a standard Yosemite install I'm just going to nuke it and see what happens. I've got plenty of backups, including the file content in this question!